# Find total pixels in the object of interest in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I would like to find the total number of pixels in an object in an image.

Consider the following image as an example. I would like to find the total number of pixels in the triangle.

[image]

I am using

```
imtool('test.jpg');
```

and using the `measure distance` tool and finding the distance manually and thus finding the area of the triangle to compute the total pixels for the object, in this case the triangle.

Is there an efficient way of doing it?

Comment: imgur is blocked at work, so I can't see exactly what's going on, but you can find edges and calculate the area within the one in question i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method:

```
img = imread('test.jpg');
thr = graythresh(img);
thr_img = im2bw(img,thr);
triangle_count = sum(sum(thr_img < thr))
```

1. Choose a threshold for the image
2. Binarize the image based on this threshold
3. Count the number of pixels below this threshold in the binarized image

In your case, the number of pixels in the triangle appears to be around 1605037.

Here's a visualization of `thr_img` -- the binarized image:

[image: Binarized Image]

Comment: I expected this would be a bit more "reliable". In Mathematica I get 1601845 with `ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate[Binarize[f]], "Count"]`. `Binarize` without parameters uses Otsu, and the threshold used can be found by `FindThreshold[f]` which returns ~0.384314. Matlab, on the other hand, gives the threshold ~0.4039. To get a closer result it is needed to first convert the image to greyscale (`rgb2gray`), then the difference is only due to the precision used in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Binarize the image and then use `bwconvhull`. [The `bwconvhull` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconvhull.html) have a good example of how to do this.